# How can I label the days of a month on this D3JS heatmap?

Tags: d3.js, calendar, heatmap

I really like the "Months > days (horizontally)" graph on this page:

http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/

I'm totally new to D3JS though and I'm wondering if its possible to label the day of the month (ie. 1,2,3...,31) directly on the calendar's HTML (not via tooltip). I basically just want to create a calendar (with labeled days) using D3JS.

How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: So you want to create an HTML table with months and days?

Comment: Yup! Basically a HTML calendar which can be populated with JSON

Comment: FYI, it's possible now with since v3

Comment: Try this one: https://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/6fd2625d3ba2b6c9ad48

Comment: @surfer190 but how do you actually put the day of the month, meaning, the number, in the square?

Comment: You can modify the code look where it is `appending a title` you can use the same thing to append `text`